# Using Holt-winters, ARIMA, exponential smoothing, etc. to forecast time series value in Python

Tags: python, forecasting

For example, if I had the following time series:

```
x = [1999, 2000, 2001, ... , 2015]
annual_sales = [10000000, 1500000, 1800000, ... , 2800000]
```

How would I forecast sales for year 2016 using Holt-Winters method in Python?

Answer (score 5):

You could use ExponentialSmoothing from [Statsmodels.tsa](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing) as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters as hw    

d = {'Year':x, 'Sales':annual_sales}
sales_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
sales_df['Year] = pd.to_datetime(sales_df['Year])
sales_df.set_index('Year', inplace=True)

model = hw.ExponentialSmoothing(sales_df).fit()
```

Once the model is generated, you can use `predict()`.

It does seem, however, that it is only available for the latest version of statsmodels. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646481/python-statsmodels-and-simple-exponential-smoothing-in-jupyter-and-pycharm). In my Windows 10 Anaconda based Python 3.6 installation, I use statsmodels 0.9.0 in which it works.

Comment: Don't just link to an solution. Explain the solution in the body of your answer.