# Python statsmodels and simple exponential smoothing in Jupyter and PyCharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python, and trying to run [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/de9a7da489e642847e7b025951cc4bb6d081564b/examples/notebooks/exponential_smoothing.ipynb) example in Jupyter notebook. Whenever I run following

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.api import SimpleExpSmoothing
```

It gives me following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a15788c08ca7> in <module>()
  3 import pandas as pd
  4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 5 from statsmodels.tsa.api import SimpleExpSmoothing
ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleExpSmoothing'
```

Although, I have installed statsmodels (0.8.0) by

```
pip install statsmodels
```

like other packages (numpy, pandas etc.). I checked on [git](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/de9a7da489e642847e7b025951cc4bb6d081564b/statsmodels/tsa/api.py), api file contains this method but my api file (obtained through pip) doesn't have this method. Maybe I am not getting the git version (seems latest one) through pip? I am working in windows and I also tried on mac OSX, and result is same. I tried to do a copy/paste attempt for missing files/code in files from git (not a good way) but it doesn't help. I would appreciate your suggestions here.

**EDIT** 
So the solution for Jupyter (thanks to @user333700) is to install master branch directly from git by

```
pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git
```

I am extending my question for PyCharm, how can I add a git package within PyCharm? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048073/install-python-package-from-github-using-pycharm) does not help.

Comment: Exponential Smoothing was merged only a while ago and is only available in statsmodels master. You will have to install the master version to use it.

Comment: @user333700 Thanks a lot, `pip install git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git` solves the problem for Jupyter.I am now wondering how a git package can be installed in PyCharm? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048073/install-python-package-from-github-using-pycharm) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference another solution which worked for me is to pip install the latest version directly:

```
pip install statsmodels==0.9.0rc1
```