# ImportError: cannot import name ExponentialSmoothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, statsmodels

I tried to install statsmodels in python. After installation, I checked with pip freeze. The package can be seen in the list.

When I am trying:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name ExponentialSmoothing
```

I have tried the following link also :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646481/python-statsmodels-and-simple-exponential-smoothing-in-jupyter-and-pycharm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same situation, and the install process recommended in Nish's url didn't work for me. Here's how did I solve the problem (I'm using Mac OS).

**Remove statsmodels library first, if you have installed**: `pip uninstall statsmodels`

1. In your terminal, type `git init`, to initiate git
2. Then type `git clone git://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git`
3. Change the directory to statsmodels using “cd statsmodels”
4. Next type `python setup.py install`
5. `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`
6. Now type `python` in your terminal and then type `from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing`, to see whether it can import successfully

Answer (score 7):

As of today (10 May 2018), the problem is solved by simply installing version 0.9.0 rather than the default 0.8.0:

```
pip install statsmodels==0.9.0rc1
```

Answer (score 1):

If using conda, this will make statsmodel 0.9.0

```
conda update statsmodels
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the wrong import,

Try

`from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps mentioned below:

Step 1: Remove statsmodel using pip uninstall statsmodel

Step 2: Install git from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Step 3: Follow steps mentioned under "Installing library(statsmodels)" from link mentioned below:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/time-series-forecasting-methods/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AnalyticsVidhya+%28Analytics+Vidhya%29