# Declare a function to do exponential smothing on data

Tags: python, function, recurrence

I am trying to do an exponential smothing in Python on some detrended data on a Jupyter notebook. I try to import

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing
```

but the following error comes up

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleExpSmoothing'
```

I don't know how to solve that problem from a Jupyter notebook, so I am trying to declare a function that does the exponential smoothing.

Let's say the function's name is `expsmoth(list,a)` and takes a list `list` and a number `a` and gives another list called `explist` whose elements are given by the following recurrence relation:

```
                  explist[0] == list[0]
                  explist[i] == a*list[i] + (1-a)*explist[i-1]
```

I am still leargnin python. How to declare a function that takes a list and a number as arguments and gives back a list whose elements are given by the above recurrence relation?

Comment: refer  this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689740/importerror-cannot-import-name-exponentialsmoothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem would be

```
def explist(data, a):
    smooth_data = data.copy()  # make a copy to avoid changing the original list
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        smooth_data[i] = a*data[i] + (1-a)*smooth_data[i-1]
    return smooth_data
```

The function should work with both native python lists or numpy arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random(100)  # some random data
smooth_data = explist(data, 0.2)
plt.plot(data, label='orginal')
plt.plot(smooth_data, label='smoothed')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of the function output.]

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of doing so but declaring first 
smooth_data = [] and after appending the values but it was giving me errors. Thanks again