# Unable to upload statsmodels 0.9rc1 python package in Azure ML studio

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, statsmodels, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm not able to upload statsmodels 0.9rc1 python package in Azure ML studio for Time series analysis.

I have downloaded [statsmodels 0.9rc1](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/6f/df6cf5faecd8082ee23916ff45d396dfee5a1f17aa275da7bab4f5c8926a/statsmodels-0.9.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl), unzipped contents and added statsmodels folder and model.pkl file to zip folder.

But, while uploading to Microsoft Azure ML studio it says **failed to build schema and visualization**

I'm using this external package in [Execute Python script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/execute-python-scripts)

PS: I have succesfully uploaded packages like Adal, dateutils etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have switched to Azure Jupyter Notebook where I installed package using pip

```
!pip install statsmodels==0.9.0rc1
```

Comment: Why do you want to install an outdated version of statsmodels?

Comment: I was getting the error ImportError: cannot import name ExponentialSmoothing 
                                                and this answer solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266200/10962477                                                                          Afterwards, I tried latest version, it is also working fine. :)